# How to loop over get_item in AWS lambda python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have 2 dynamodb both table `id` is the short key. sample json for both tables is below

Table1

```
 [{"id": 1,"completed": false }, {"id": 2, "completed": false }]
```

Table2

```
[{"id": 13,"completed": false }, {"id": 2, "completed": false }]
```

Code is below

```
table1 = dynamodb.Table('employee1')
table2 = dynamodb.Table('employee2')
for eid in listofeid:
    repsonse = table.get_item(Key={'id': eid})
```

Table1 is primary table to check with Table2
I need to compare the table1 & table2 retrieve the data if the id exists in both table using `get_item`

This I need to test for 100 ids

I have done with Table.scan(). How to do with table.get_item

Comment: Why are these separate tables? Can they be combined to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the straightforward solution is just to do a `BatchGetItem` on the 100 ids on both tables separately, and then doing the intersection in the application.

One can argue that this is inefficient - you will still need to pay for 200 reads even if just 50 ids exist in each table and the intersection is just 10 items. The question is whether an alternative solution would have been more efficient. The answer is probably - a bit, but not by much. A single-table solution (as suggested by Kirk) would have allowed you to do this with just 100 reads. But there is no magic way that you can just find the intersection immediately, paying for reading just the intersection.

Comment: can you answer below question I have tried but could not succeed    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64598874/how-to-loop-extract-element-from-dynamodb-recursively